# Display two columns with a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` such as

```
A  B  C
0  a  1
1  b  1
2  c  2
```

I would like to return `B`, and `C` when `C==1`, like so

```
B  C
a  1
b  1
```

I've got as far as `df.B[df.C==1]`, which returns

```
B
a
b
```

which is right (countwise) but wrong in the slice. How do I get `C`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print df.loc[df.C==1, ['B','C']]
   B  C
0  a  1
1  b  1

print df[['B','C']].query('C == 1')
   B  C
0  a  1
1  b  1
```

Or if you need only column `C`:

```
print df.loc[df.C==1, 'C']

0    1
1    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: dammit. thank you. I tried that, but used `df.loc[df.C==1, [df.B,df.C]]`... D: don't know why that didn't work, but yours did (just the strings)... anyway, I'll accept in 10 mins as per the rules.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!